# MongoDB driver installed but does not work

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, composer-php

I've installed a MongoDB driver but something is obviously wrong since it doesn't work. This is what I did:

- `sudo pecl install mongodb`
- pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.7

`phpinfo()` returns that MongoDB is installed

Also, var_dump(extension_loaded('mongodb')); returns as a true.

When I execute "php composer.phar update" I get the following message:

root@debian:/var/www/html# php composer.phar update
Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.5 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.4 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.5 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-mongodb ^2.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-mongodb[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-memcached.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ext-mongo` is a different extension than `ext-mongodb` (latter being newer). If Yii2 does not support new one yet then you may try using a polyfill such as [alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that on my local machine it works. I've basically copied my composer.json and on the production machine it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like locally you have both extensions installed while server has only new `ext-mongodb`

Comment: I think you are right. When I try with `phpinfo();` I can see that there is a "mongo" and "mongodb".

Comment: Yep. You were right. Yii2 doesn't support newer one, so I'm using the old one. I hope they will support the new version as well. Thanks.